# Create a dynamic array of id's in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a web application where situation is like that
"When a user clicks on Mark as Favorite button, jquery picks the id of that user(i.e marked favorite)" and calls ajax. Now here I want to create an array which stores all these id's and then I will store this array into wordpress user_meta_field. But problem is that each time ajax creates a new array and does not store the id in the same array. Here is my code

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('.fav-<?php echo $myID; ?>').click(function(){

var user_IDs = jQuery(this).attr('id');
var current_IDs = <?php echo $cui ?>;

jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'ajaxreturn=101&id='+user_IDs+'&myid='+current_IDs,
            success: function(result){
                jQuery('.testres').html(result);
                }

                    });//ajax ends here 
});
                });
```

and here is the code generates response in functions.php

```
add_action('init','my_ajaxreturn_101');
function my_ajaxreturn_101(){
$reminders = array();   
if($_POST['ajaxreturn']==101){

$userID = $_POST['id']; 
 $loggedID = $_POST['myid'];


  array_push($reminders,json_decode(get_user_meta($loggedID, 'meta_favorite', true), true));
  array_unique($reminders);


        if(in_array($_POST['id'],$reminders)) {
            echo "Failed: Auction already in list";
        } else {
            array_push($reminders,intval($_POST['id']));

            if(update_user_meta( $loggedID, 'meta_favorite', json_encode($reminders) )) {
                echo "Success";
            } 
        }

        print_r($reminders);

exit;


    }

    }
```

and here is the output of first click

```
SuccessArray ( [0] => [1] => 39 )
```

Here is the output of second click

```
SuccessArray ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => 39 ) [1] => 34 )
```

and Here is the output of third click

```
SuccessArray ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => 39 ) [1] => 34 ) [1] => 33 )
```

Comment: Since the array is not global you cant achieve this but if you store the array in session variable you can achieve it

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. Can you write a little bit of code here how to do this. thanks

Comment: sure check the first answer

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
array_push($_SESSION['reminders'],json_decode(get_user_meta($loggedID, 'meta_favorite', true), true));
array_unique($_SESSION['reminders']);
```

You can print the array like

```
print_r($_SESSION['reminders']);
```

Note: before you push into session you must start the session for a user

change these lines:

```
...
} else {
    array_push($_SESSION['reminders'],intval($_POST['id']));
    if(update_user_meta( $loggedID, 'meta_favorite', json_encode($reminders) )) {
       echo "Success";
    } 
}
...
```

Comment: Sorry Viswanath Polaki, its not working. It only stores one value..and only prints "success"

Comment: its the response from the ajax. try to print the session in another link or just print the array instead of success in the if else statement

Comment: you can view it here http://dev.optimizebusinessgrowth.com/gopaperboy/members/. please click on red heart icon in each box

Comment: problem still persists. you can view it here http://awesomescreenshot.com/0af2g03d00

Comment: ok, then remove the echo "success"; line and change it to print_r($_SESSION['reminders']; and check it again.

Comment: Sorry Viswanath Polaki, it still not working. When I checked it, it is sending the request as it should, but there is no respnse now.

Comment: ok, create a new url where you start the session and print the complete array of session and then check it.

Comment: session is not storing any value.  the print_r(session) gives Array ( [reminders] => )

Comment: Hi can you provide the complete code which you are using because i have no idea about the function update_user_meta

Comment: where should I send it to you? because this comment section is limited to few characters.

Comment: if you want you can edit your question or you can send it to email id polaki_2005@yahoo.com